# dropwizard metrics and API timing

Tags: dropwizard, graphite

I'm trying to do very simple performance measurement of some of my APIs to determine how long they take.
I've added a test resource:

```
private static final MetricRegistry metrics = new MetricRegistry();
private final Timer responses = metrics.timer("test_responses");

@GET
public void test() {
    final Timer.Context context = responses.time();
    try {
        log.info("sleeping...");
        Thread.sleep(10*1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } finally {
        context.stop();//2
    }
}
```

and added the folllowing to my main Application class:

```
ConsoleReporter reporter = ConsoleReporter.forRegistry(metrics).convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS).convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
    reporter.start(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Every ten seconds I see:

6/13/16 11:38:51 AM ============================================================

6/13/16 11:39:01 AM ============================================================

But nothing provided about the "test_responses" metric I created. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you invoke your test method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you use 2 instances of the metric registry. Look at this example:

```
public class Application extends io.dropwizard.Application<Configuration>{

    @Override
    public void run(Configuration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
        MetricRegistry metrics = environment.metrics();
        environment.jersey().register(new HelloResource(metrics));

        ConsoleReporter.forRegistry(metrics).build().start(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Application().run("server", "/home/artur/dev/repo/sandbox/src/main/resources/config/test.yaml");
    }
}
```

I am using the metrics registry that DW creates for you. This MR also includes the Jetty stats.

My resource:

```
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HelloResource {

    private MetricRegistry service;

    public HelloResource(MetricRegistry service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GET
    public String hello() {

        Timer timer = service.timer("test");

        try(Context t = timer.time()) {
            return "Hello World";
        }

    }
}
```

And the output:

```
test
             count = 3
         mean rate = 0.89 calls/second
     1-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
     5-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
    15-minute rate = 0.00 calls/second
               min = 0.00 milliseconds
               max = 0.01 milliseconds
              mean = 0.00 milliseconds
            stddev = 0.00 milliseconds
            median = 0.00 milliseconds
              75% <= 0.01 milliseconds
              95% <= 0.01 milliseconds
              98% <= 0.01 milliseconds
              99% <= 0.01 milliseconds
            99.9% <= 0.01 milliseconds
```

I have invoked the test method 3 times, and you can see the stats recorded by the MetricRegistry.

I hope that solves your issue.

Regards,

artur